# NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.FieldSerializer.<init>

Tags: scala, apache-spark, json4s

Spark version - 2.4.0

Scala version - 2.11.1

json4s version - 3.5.3

Getting error - `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.FieldSerializer.<init>(Lscala/PartialFunction;Lscala/PartialFunction;Lscala/reflect/Manifest;)V`

```
import org.json4s.FieldSerializer._
val metricSerializer = FieldSerializer[Metric](
    renameTo("metricType", "metric_type"),
    renameFrom("metric_type", "metricType")
  )
```

This works if used outside of Spark.

Comment: The lib version at runtime is not the one declared as build dependency

Answer (score 0):

Try use latest version 3.6.7.

val json4sJackson = "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.6.7"